# Need Info from different id on the same table Laravel

Tags: php, sql, laravel

I need a query that gives me the name of the ***creator*** of the specific ***person*** 
.I have a table with **persons** where there are two ids...

> person_id creator_id

The person has a name also the creator has a name,
So i need the name for the creator of the specific person,
there is model **Person** controller everything.I am currently working on the edit blade of the person and all the info is in the same table.

**TRIED**

I tried creating a method in my model to somehow join the creator id to the person id but i failed

**EDIT**

More info..for example a person with id = 10 has

> person_id = 10 , person_name = john , creator_id = 20

but the creator is also a person_id which has the name george
,there are all in the same table so im confused i also tried this in my edit controller

```
$creators_name = DB::table('Persons')
        ->select('person_name')
        ->where('Persons.person_id,'=',Persons.creator_id)
        ->where(Persons.person_id,'=',$id)
        ->get();
```

I need something like this to call it in my blade !

Comment: Try `join` with same table for creator name.

Comment: @ShaluSinghal i tried joining the creator_id = person_id but i failed...

Comment: Do you have any code worth sharing?

Comment: @JeffPuckettII i just did thx for any help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this query

```
SELECT person.name as personName, creator.name as creatorName
FROM person
JOIN person AS creator ON creator.id = person.creator_id
```

**Update**

in laravel way

```
$result = DB::table('Persons')
        ->join('Persons as creator', 'creator.id', '=', 'Persons.creator_id')
        ->select('Persons.name as personName', 'creator.name as creatorName')
        ->where(Persons.id, '=', $id)
        ->get();
```

I am assumming you have primary key or person_id as `id`